# python: access "cousin" .txt file

Tags: python, directory

I have a directory structure like this:

```
project
  gamelib
    game.py
  levels
    level1.txt
```

I need game.py to access level1.txt.

```
with open(path, "r") as f:
  ...
```

how do i access the path of level1.txt?

Comment: That depends on what you *working* directory is at that moment...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Doesn't it really depend on the location of `game.py`, which may not be related in any particular way to the working directory?

Comment: @ScottHunter: afaik if you call it with `python game.py` and the path is relative, it will work from that path.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem True, but question says nothing about where the code is called from, nor that the working directory has not changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either give it the full path

```
with open("/usr/yourUser/../project/levels/level1.txt", "r") as f:
```

or a relative path (this considers that your script *game.py* is located at *./project* level)

```
with open("./levels/level1.txt", "r") as f:
```

**in your example, you have to travel back**:

```
with open("../levels/level1.txt", "r") as f:
```

Comment: I updated my answer. You just have to locate the file, same as if you are in the location of your script and do a `ls` command to list the file you want.